# API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

When calling Places in a social engine install Google is responding in the console with the error ?libraries=places&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&c=17:61 This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend?project=_ For more information on authentication and Google Maps JavaScript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

and this panel 
see https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9NuE.jpg

Other versions of this question appear to be pre the current version and/or answer was activating additional api's

The only thing I noticed was the lack of a project id in the Develops console link indicating the api key is not connecting

I've made sure that places, geocoding, maps javascript etc. are all enabled and also tried the fix of disabling/re-enabling each of the services.

see https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOfZb.jpg

The API key is correct

I checked billing details are up to date

The address that is being called is correct AFAIK `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&amp;key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;c=17"></script>`

Additionally I've made sure the url is listed in the allowed domains as both www.womensadventureclub.com.au & womensadventureclub.com.au

The domain has been added to the Search Console and verified (listing as https://www.womensadventureclub.com.au)

This is a plugin so not my own code but it appears to be accurately reaching google but the API key is not being recognised.

Any ideas what else I could try or if there is something I'm missing?

Thanks
Brad

Comment: Can you try (1) re-enabling billing (2) creating a new api key (leaving it temporarily unrestricted for testing purposes only) and if the previous 2 solutions fail, (3) creating a brand new project and relinking it to your billing account? Note that if these solutions don't resolve the issue you may need to contact maps tech support: https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#contact_maps_support

Comment: Thanks Evan I tried re-enabling billing with no success then created an unrestricted api key and that did the trick. 

I'll try adding my restrictions back in one at a time to try to id what the failure point was for future reference

Comment: Testing my restrictions it looks like Http referrers was wrong
I used 
````(*).womensadventureclub.com.au/* ```` due to misreading the example 
 
````Any URL in a single subdomain, using a wildcard asterisk (*): sub.example.com/*````

 
Using ````(*)://*.womensadventureclub.com.au/*```` works

Comment: Happy to hear! And thanks for your update, you may want to answer your own question for the community's sake :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was an incorrect restriction in http referrers
I was using `(*).womensadventureclub.com.au/*` due to misreading the example `Any URL in a single subdomain, using a wildcard asterisk (*): sub.example.com/*`

I then thought that using `(*)://*.womensadventureclub.com.au/*` would fix the issue but found in another area it failed. Changing to `https://www.womensadventureclub.com.au/* & https://womensadventureclub.com.au/*` fixed it